# Django: how to exclude page being deleted from the object list in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm developing a Django website which has a section (an app) "About" with 3-level hierarchy of pages. This section has corresponding 3-level popup menu. In order to minimize queries to the database, I want this menu to be static (html file), rewritten only in cases if the menu changes (i. e. on page create, update or delete).

This operation is done by the function **get_success_url**:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    object_list = Page.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by("order").prefetch_related("subpages__subpages")
    text = render_to_string('menu_pages_template.html', {'object_list': object_list})
    f = open( 'roo/templates/includes/menu_about.html', 'w+')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
    ...
```

On page creation or update everything works well. However, on page deletion, its menu item is not deleted, because the page object still exists in the queryset.

I tried to exclude current object from the queryset:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    object_list = Page.objects.exclude(slug=self.kwargs['page'])
    object_list = object_list.filter(parent=None).order_by("order").prefetch_related("subpages__subpages")
```

But this approach works only with first-level pages. The "child" and "grandchild" pages still remain in the queryset. Possibly they could be also excluded by some filtering, but I suspect that there should be more simple and "pythonic" way to exclude deleted page from the queryset.

So, please help me!

Comment: Can you clarify "Page object still exists in the queryset"? If you deleted after evaluating the queryset the first time, you will either have to re-evaluate it, or keep a list of deleted pages and exclude them with Python code.

Comment: If I understand it right, the function **get_success_url** is run **after** the model instance is removed from the database. However, if I run a command inside this function: `object_list = Page.objects.all()`, this instance is still there (in the object list). Possibly the instance at this moment is not actually deleted from the database. I understand what you mean by re-evaluating, but give me a hint how to do this. Actually what I want is that the instance was deleted **before** the function get_success_url is implemented. Or I can use another function of the model, which is the very last.

Comment: Finally, I kind of solved this problem by moving the code from my views (get_success_url method) to the model. I overrode the standard method save() to make it write changes to the HTML file **after** the change was saved.

`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`
`super().save(*args, **kwargs)`
`object_list = Page.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by("order").prefetch_related("subpages__subpages")`
`text = render_to_string('menu_pages_template.html', {'object_list': object_list})`
`f = open( 'roo/templates/includes/menu_about.html', 'w+')`
`f.write(text)`
`f.close()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm baffled as to how an object can be returned, if it's genuinely been deleted before the query in `get_success_url()` is executed. However, I don't have any experience with models that have Foreign keys to themselves. (I presume that's what "parent" is with related name "subpages")? I'm thinking it's not actually deleted (yet?) and I'd be very carefully reading the Django description for database transaction commits, and possibly the documentation of the DB you are using. Is it a "feature"? Or even a bug in the code you didn't write? Something being cached, which shouldn't be?

A (simple!) sledgehammer you might try is to add a `has_been_deleted` BooleanField to the Page model, and do this:

```
# page is to be deleted
page.has_been_deleted = True
page.save()
print( f"About to delete Page instance pk={page.pk}") # for debug
page.delete()
```

which ought to be completely redundant, but you could then investigate whether the simple query works right after you add an explicit Prefetch object to exclude deleted objects. Following the Django doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), something like

```
object_list = Page.objects.filter(
       parent=None, 
       # has_been_deleted=False # necessary?
   ).order_by("order"
   ).prefetch_related( Prefetch( 
       "subpages__subpages",
        queryset = Page.objects.exclude(has_been_deleted=True)
        )
   )
```

and if you still have the same problem, is `has_been_deleted` set in the object which is retrieved, and does that object have the same pk or not?

Also were I testing using a development DB rather than a test DB (which starts the test completely empty of objects), I'd check very carefully that there aren't any page objects left behind by earlier code which didn't quite work.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've found following approach, which I don't actually like, but it works. First, I generate different lists for pages of 1st level (parent_list), 2nd level (child_list) and 3rd level (grandchild_list), excluding from all the lists my current instance, which is page being deleted.
Next, I prefetch "grandchildren" to "children", and, finally, "children" to "parents". The code is below. I find it ugly and very complicated, so I'm still looking the better way.

```
class PageDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Page
    success_url = reverse_lazy('about:detail')

    def get_object(self):
        page = Page.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['page'])
        return page
    
    def get_success_url(self):    
        total_list = Page.objects.exclude(slug=self.kwargs['page'])
        descendant_list = total_list.filter(parent__isnull=False).order_by("order")
        grandchild_list = descendant_list.filter(parent__parent__isnull=False).order_by("order")
        child_list = descendant_list.filter(parent__parent__isnull=True).order_by("order")
        parent_list = total_list.filter(parent__isnull=True)        
        child_list = child_list.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('subpages', queryset=grandchild_list)
            )
        object_list = parent_list.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('subpages', queryset=child_list)
            )
        text = render_to_string('menu_pages_template.html', {'object_list': object_list})
        f = open( 'roo/templates/includes/menu_about.html', 'w+')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()
        return reverse('about:detail')
```